# 3D matrix creation in Matlab with no 3 argument zeros function supported

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, labview

I need to create a 3D array or matrix in Matlab that is later on supported in LabVIEW's Mathscript node. All the values in the 3D array should be initialized to 0 and the sizes along the 3 dimensions are different precalculated variables.

I tried the following:
 `X = zeros(a,b,c);` which works fine for Matlab, but in LabVIEW the zeros function only support 1 or 2 arguments.

Then I tried by creating it with a for loop:

```
for i = 1 to c
    X(:,:,i) = zeros(a,b);
end
```

However, nor the array indexing support 3 indexes. I get the error:

> "You can specify only one or two index arguments, such as a(1, 2)."

Do you have any ideas how to create a 3D array not using the zeros function with 3 arguments and neither the array indexing with 3 arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search online, I found [this page](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/373123B-01/lvtextmathmain/mathscript_data_types/) describing supported [data types](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/lvhowto/hiq_and_matlab_data_types/) in LabVIEW MathScript:

> Scalars and One- and Two-Dimensional Arrays
>
> - Single-precision, floating-point numeric
> - Double-precision, floating-point numeric
> - Extended-precision, floating-point numeric
> - Complex single-precision, floating-point numeric
> - Complex double-precision, floating-point numeric
> - Complex extended-precision, floating-point numeric
> - 8-bit signed integer numeric
> - 16-bit signed integer numeric
> - 32-bit signed integer numeric
> - 64-bit signed integer numeric
> - 8-bit unsigned integer numeric
> - 16-bit unsigned integer numeric
>     32-bit unsigned integer numeric
> - 64-bit unsigned integer numeric
> - Boolean
> - Structure

So it appears that 3D arrays (or higher dims) are not supported.

You can also confirm by checking the [`zeros`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/373123B-01/lvtextmath/msfunc_zeros/) function documentation.

Comment: Well, this is a huge problem for me right now. Didn't even think that they are not supported. Do you have any ideas of a workaround that could "simulate" somehow 3D arrays? Without this structure my whole algorithm is killed.

Comment: @rafanadal Not sure, it depend on your application.. Perhaps you can flatten the third dimension and and tuck it horizontally as 2D matrix. So instead of creating `arr3d=zeros(m,n,p)` you create `arr2d=zeros(m,n*p)`. Of course you'll have to adjust all indexing into this array, so whenever you need to access `arr3d(:,:,i)` you instead slice the 2d matrix as `arr2d(:,(i-1)*n+1:i*n)`

Comment: That's a good idea. I like it. As the data in all cells is independent and the 3 dimensions were only used for proper indexing flattening should work, I just need to careful not to mess up the indexing. Thanks!